# Scrolling large tile map using cocos2d-x gives me black tiles where there should be green tiles

Tags: cocos2d-x, tmx

I am loading 400x400 tile map created using Tiled software.
One tile is 120 pixels for total of 48000x48000 pixels.

I load like this

```
    regionMap->initWithTMXFile("background2.tmx");
    mapLayer->addChild(regionMap, 0, enTagTileMap);
    mapLayer->setAnchorPoint(CCPoint(0,1));
```

Then I scroll like this.

```
    mapLayer->setPosition(position);
```

When I vertically scroll to about this position, I do not get the tiles from the map anymore, I just get black tiles.

```
    x=0 , y=5483.748535
```

When I horizontally scroll, I do not get the same problem even when I reach this position.

```
    x=-48000, y=400
```

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fair to assume that cocos2d-x's tilemap renderer is a direct port of the one in cocos2d-iphone. If true, they both have the same restriction of a maximum of 65,536 vertices (16,384 tiles) that can be displayed (not counting empty tiles).

Your tilemap is 400x400 = 160,000 tiles assuming there is only one layer and there aren't any "empty" tiles (empty == tile locations with GID value 0). That means about ten times the number of tiles cocos2d will/can render.

Cocos2d will just render up to 16,384 tiles and then stop, the remaining tiles will not be rendered so you'll see the background color (default: black).

A common but awkward workaround is to split the map into several TMX files and align them in code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried with 200x200 tile map, and it also stops rendering at about y=80. The tilemap contains one layer that is all filled with tiles from the same texture. So I thought it is only about 16,000 not 65,536 tiles that can be rendered by cocos2d-x. I tried 125x125 and it worked correctly, but that is too limited to be believable. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's 65k vertices but each tile has 4 vertices so that makes 16k tiles.

Comment: Contemplate splitting it into multiple tilemaps and loading/unloading them dynamically as your character gets near the edges. You should be able to deftly avoid these limits this way.